# How to close a task waiting on a server socket listen?

Tags: sockets, ada

I have a program, written in Ada (although for this purpose I'm interested in any solution). It has a task in it that won't shut down without a sigkill (the program handles SIGUSR1) because it's waiting on a server socket it's created. The SIGUSR1 is handled correctly, but this task won't terminate unless something is fed onto the socket, at which point it can then check the shutdown status and close normally. However I want to do this without having to stuff data in on the socket. If anyone knows a good way of doing this, that would be great. Suggestions so far, that are not appropriate are things like timing out and reopening the socket because that may interfere with the socket's usage.

Answer (score 4):

I am assuming you are using the GNAT Ada compiler and when using that compiler there is a compiler specific package called GNAT.Sockets which is a cross-platform API for sockets. The intended usage of this package for being able to develop applications that can be shutdown nicely is to use the GNAT.Sockets.Check_Selector procedure. The socket reader task uses Check_Selector to know if there is data to be read from the socket before calling Receive_Socket. Another task can abort the blocking call Check_Selector of the socket reader task by calling Abort_Selector. I hope this will point you in the right direction.

Comment: I've wondered about Abort_Selector.  I've never used it.  Does Check_Selector actually block the current task like a protected entry would?  I've always gone the route of doing non blocking sockets so I could manually exit whenever another task requested it, so I've never tried using Abort_Selector before.

Comment: The subprogram Check_Selector has an out argument of type Selector_Status which tells why the Check_Selector subprogram has stopped blocking. If the status is Expired it is the timeout that expired and one can call Check_Selector again. If the status is Completed there is then for example data to read. If the status is aborted then another task has called Abort_Selector. Using Check_Selector has worked very well for me to be able to easily stop an application without using non blocking sockets. Both solutions work.